# Error initializing SparkContext. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to create `SparkContext` object in below code from my Windows 10 Desktop:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;

public class MyTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("");
        conf.setMaster("local");
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    }
}
```

Using maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0-cdh5.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also set `HADOOP_HOME=C:\winutil` where `C:\winutil\bin\winutils.exe` is present of 64-bits.

While running the above code getting below error message:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/farooque/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/farooque/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.4.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/12/01 10:44:01 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
17/12/01 10:46:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/12/01 10:46:28 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: farooque
17/12/01 10:46:28 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: farooque
17/12/01 10:46:28 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(farooque); users with modify permissions: Set(farooque)
17/12/01 10:47:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 52602.
17/12/01 10:48:46 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
17/12/01 10:48:57 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
17/12/01 10:49:06 ERROR Remoting: Remoting error: [Startup timed out] [
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup timed out
    at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:129)
    at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:191)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:579)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1989)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1980)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:462)
    at com.xyz.module.submodule.incoming.test.validator.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:173)
    ... 18 more
]
17/12/01 10:49:06 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:173)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:579)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1989)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1980)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:462)
    at com.xyz.module.submodule.incoming.test.validator.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:11)
17/12/01 10:49:08 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:173)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:579)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1989)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1980)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:462)
    at com.xyz.module.submodule.incoming.test.validator.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:11)
```

Not being able to create Spark context object. Error is thrown at `SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);`. Looking for the help!!!

Comment: But I am using Spark 1.6.0

Comment: are you using spark-shell? can you check if you gave the correct hostname and that if its resolved it correctly

Comment: @ChitralVerma: I have updated my question. Please look into the question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved!

Let me share the real cause and how it got resolved?

Initially the code was present in a network drive(say `Z:\workspace\...`) but execution of the code was happening locally on the machine. To create a `SparkContext` object by taking the code from network drive `[Startup timed out]` was happening, (assumption slow network speed)causes the issue.

**Solution:**

So I moved the code in local drive(say `C:\Users\farooque\workspace\...`) and ran the code again, now `SparkContext` got created successfully. Hence the issue got resolved!